# Not getting results using python scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

This is my first Scrapy program, i couldn't see the results even executed without errors.

```
import scrapy

class sageSpyder(scrapy.Spider):
    name= 'sagespyder'
    start_url = [
        'https://journals.sagepub.com/action/doSearch?AllField=cancer'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for item in response.xpath("//div//ol[@class='search-results']//li"):
            yield {
                'art_title': item.xpath(".//article//h2//span//a//text()").extract_first()
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in start_url**s**:

```
start_urls = [
    'https://journals.sagepub.com/action/doSearch?AllField=cancer'
]
```

Also you'll need (in `settings.py`):

```
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False
```

Comment: Thnaks its working, using this command 'scrapy crawl sagespyder -o data.json' i have executed in CMD, but can you tell me how to run this code in pycharm.